# Color text in a table

Tags: tables, color

Is there a way to color text in an entire table without using environment tabular? For example, change the color of text in every cell to red.

Comment: Which tabular-like environmet(s) do you use?

Comment: I use tabular environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you thing on something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{red}}c >{\color{red}}c}
    \hline
A   &   B   \\
C   &   D   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

If you wish in red (or other selected color) entire table (with lines), than before table just put command `\color{red}`

Answer (score 20):

Just use

```
{\color{red}\begin{tabular}{cc}
a&b\\
1&2
\end{tabular}}
```

and the table will be red.

Answer (score 2):

Previous posts work for coloring individual columns or whole table contexts in latex. But while using this code for any latex template of a journal you have to write the package `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` just next to the `\documentclass{standalone}`, otherwise, the code will not work. for e.g.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
```

Again for coloring individual texts of a table, you can use

```
\begin{tabular}{l l }

    \toprule
    1   &   \textcolor{blue}{Water}  \\
    2   &   Hippo grass  \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: But the question is about not have to set the color in every cell ... With respect to `xcolor` package, sometimes is not needed, because it is already loaded by the document class or another package, and in this case you do not need the [table] option . Also, although sometimes the order of the packages matter, usually it must be simply in any place of preamble, no just under the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: How can I color a whole row with many elements?