# Colour only the text in a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

Edit: This question is related to this one: [How to change only the color of numbers (and not units) with numprint?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467560/138900)

I tried the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246666/138900), but it enlarges the line spacing of the table as shown in the second example in the screenshot below.

[image: capture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,numprint,tabularx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

Tabularx table \textbf{without} any color: \textbf{the spacing is normal.}


\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|*{11}{X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\rm m^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm dm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm cm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm mm^2$} \\
\hline
&&&4,&&&& \\
&&&4&0&0&0& 0,\\
&0,&0&4&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip

Tabularx table \textbf{with} colors: \textbf{the line spacing is enlarged.}

\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|*{11}{>{\color{blue}}X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\rm m^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm dm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm cm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm mm^2$} \\
\hline
&&&4,&&&& \\
&&&4&0&0&0& 0,\\
&0,&0&4&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip


Table with individually placed colours. \textbf{No problem at all.}

\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|*{11}{X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\rm m^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm dm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm cm^2$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\rm mm^2$} \\
\hline
&&&\textcolor{blue}{4,}&&&& \\
&&&\textcolor{blue}{4}&\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{blue}{0}& \textcolor{blue}{0},\\
&\textcolor{blue}{0,}&\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{blue}{4}&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

#### How to color the text without coloring the rest of the table?

Comment: Excuse me very much. Why you use `\rm` in mathmode? Very beautiful your hat :)

Comment: Actually, I don't remember why, it's an old document and I'm trying to change the color of the text.

Comment: `>{\leavevmode\color{blue}}X|}` instead of `>{\color{blue}}X|}`

Comment: @moewe great, Can you turn this comment into a answer?

Comment: The question is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31547/35864 then. Would you agree?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347319/35864

Comment: @moewe Yes, you're right.

Comment: Good. Voted to close.

Comment: Off topic: The 'modern' way to typeset units is with the `siunitx` package. `siunitx` even has facilities similar to those of the `numprint` package.

Comment: @moewe: I planned to post an answer with `siunitx`, which would also solve the color problem, but now the question is closed ...

Comment: @moewe I have a problem with the font that appears in the beamer class.  For reasons of readability of the font characters, I prefer numprint. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440572/138900

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you ask for reopening, I vote yes for a new answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Please revoke your vote for reopening

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Okay, but how do I do that? I'm not pulling out of the reopening.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's a real pity because a solution with sinuitx can be interesting because here the units are square meters and not litres.

Comment: @moewe Now that Christian Hupfer has indicated a solution with siunitx, it would be good, in my opinion, for you to give the solution you have commented on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Color changes cell height in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31547/35864) and [Xcolor breaks tabular cell alignment when using the p option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347319/35864) the `\color` command can be used between paragraphs and therefore does not switch the mode TeX is in. That means that in the table the `\colour` command is added to the vertical list and the colour actually starts 'before' the paragraph containing the contents of the cell and leaves a bit of vertical space.

If you add `\leavevmode` before the `\color` command you force TeX out of vertical mode and cause the colour to start at the beginning of the paragraph for the cell content. No vertical space is inserted because the vertical list is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
Tabularx table \textbf{with} colors and \texttt{\string\leavevmode}: \textbf{normal again.}

\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|*{11}{>{\leavevmode\color{blue}}X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\si{\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\deci\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\centi\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\milli\metre\squared}} \\
\hline
&&&4,&&&& \\
&&&4&0&0&0& 0,\\
&0,&0&4&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Like [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467564/35864) I recommend using `siunitx` at least for the units (if only to get rid of the two-letter font command `\rm`, see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/35864)).

Answer (score 6):

A preliminary solution, using `siunitx` and a regular `tabular` instead of `tabularx` and applying the `S` - columntype.

The `S` - columntype has the advantage of aligning decimal numbers as well as using the appropriate number formatting.

The `number-color=` option colorizes the numbers only, in order to prevent powers of units to be colored as well, use `power-font=unit` and in order to keep the comma as decimal marker, use `copy-decimal-marker`.

Please note that `|`, i.e. vertical lines are arguable with respect to design and readability of tables, but I kept them inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{number-color=blue,power-font=unit,copy-decimal-marker}

\begin{document}

Tabularx table \textbf{without} any color: \textbf{the spacing is normal.}


\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{S|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\si{\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\deci\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\centi\metre\squared}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\si{\milli\metre\squared}} \tabularnewline
\hline
&&&4,&&&& \tabularnewline
&&&4&0&0&0& 0,\tabularnewline
&0&0&4&&&& \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: the small 'debris' above the table are cut-outs from the screen-shot. They have nothing to to with the table itself

Comment: Is it possible not to put 0 after the comma?`0,` and not `0,0`. Children are taught to write only one number per column. The comma is only used to teach children that it is the unit marker.

Comment: @AndréC: Perhaps it is possible, but that is bad style. I am a teacher as well and you should **not** teach children such styles!

Comment: In a table I only allow one number per column. Putting two is a problem. The comma is only placed for educational purposes to teach them how to use a conversion table.  The rest of the time, they are not allowed to put a comma without numbers after it.